# How to get first or first two digits from "12345-678" using a substring C# Console

Tags: c#, arrays, substring

I am creating a C# Console app which is Replacing a Hyphen for Zeros to complete the maximum length of my String from an identification card "123456-72"and I am facing a hard time when have to sort in my array.

I would like sort the first digit or character from this "**1**23456-72" as well in some cases I need to sort from the first two digit "**39**1234-56".

This example is working fine, but only for first character. I need to 
Example:

```
class IdentificationNumber {

    private string IDNumber;
    private int Customertype;
    private string check;
    private string pad;
    private string longFormat;

    SortedList GroupID = new SortedList();

    public IdentificationNumber(string IDNumber) {
        this.IDNumber= IDNumber;
    }

    public string getLongFormat() {
        var ReplaceHyp = IDNumber.Replace("-", "");
        int Customertype= Int32.Parse(IDNumber.Substring(0,2));

        //Array 
        //GroupID .Add(1,"Blue");
        //GroupID .Add(2,"Blue");
        GroupID .Add(38,"White");
        GroupID .Add(39,"Blue");

        pad=""; 
        check = GroupID.GetByIndex(GroupID.IndexOfKey(Customertype)).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(Customertype);
        Console.WriteLine(check);

        switch (check) { 
            case("White"):
                longFormat= ReplaceHyp.Substring(0,6)+pad.PadLeft((14 -ReplaceHyp.Length),'0')+ReplaceHyp.Substring(6,(ReplaceHyp.Length-6));
                break;

            case("Blue"):
                longFormat= ReplaceHyp.Substring(0,7)+pad.PadLeft((14 -ReplaceHyp.Length),'0')+ReplaceHyp.Substring(7,(ReplaceHyp.Length-7));
                break;
        }

        return longFormat;
    }
}
```

Any solution or suggestion?

Comment: To do a sort, please [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389903/custom-sorting-of-a-string-array-in-c-sharp); I cannot answer your question any further without knowing, for instance, why do you sometimes use one character and other times two. For a custom `SortedList`, you need to use the `SortedList(IComparer)` constructor.

Comment: @KenY-N. Because I have two different kind of account Type in one case I am replacing the Hyphen  and adding zeros from: 7th position(0,6) "White" and in other hands from 8th position (0,7) "Blue" Thanks for ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a skeleton of the comparator method you might need:

```
public static int CompareStrings(string s1, string s2)
{
    int Customertype1 = Int32.Parse(s1.Substring(0,2));
    int Customertype2 = Int32.Parse(s2.Substring(0,2));

    string check1 = GroupID.GetByIndex(GroupID.IndexOfKey(Customertype1)).ToString();
    string check2 = GroupID.GetByIndex(GroupID.IndexOfKey(Customertype2)).ToString();

    if (Customertype1 > Customertype2)
        return 1;
    if (Customertype1 < Customertype2)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        var ReplaceHyp1 = s1.Replace("-", "");
        switch (check1) { 
            case("White"):
                longFormat1 = ReplaceHyp1.Substring(0,6)+pad.PadLeft((14 -ReplaceHyp1.Length),'0')+ReplaceHyp1.Substring(6,(ReplaceHyp1.Length-6));
                break;

            case("Blue"):
                longFormat1 = ReplaceHyp1.Substring(0,7)+pad.PadLeft((14 -ReplaceHyp1.Length),'0')+ReplaceHyp1.Substring(7,(ReplaceHyp1.Length-7));
                break;
        }
        var ReplaceHyp2 = s2.Replace("-", "");
        switch (check2) { 
            case("White"):
                longFormat2 = ReplaceHyp2.Substring(0,6)+pad.PadLeft((14 -ReplaceHyp2.Length),'0')+ReplaceHyp2.Substring(6,(ReplaceHyp2.Length-6));
                break;

            case("Blue"):
                longFormat2 = ReplaceHyp2.Substring(0,7)+pad.PadLeft((14 -ReplaceHyp2.Length),'0')+ReplaceHyp2.Substring(7,(ReplaceHyp2.Length-7));
                break;
        }
        return stringCompare(longFormat1, longFormat2);
    }
}
```

This code badly needs to be refactored! Depending on your exact needs, I think that the checks of `Customertype1/2` can be removed.